# REACTJS Pass variable through const using fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, jsx

I have my function here to fetch some stuff from the openweather API that I'm using.

```js
const [ForecastFind, setForecastFind] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=22&lon=151&exclude=current,minutely,daily&APPID=TOKEN',
  )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setForecastFind(data.hourly[0].dt))
}, [])
```

This works fine when i'm using it like this:

```
<div className="DescriptionsSplitter" style={{ marginTop: '-20vh' }}>
  {ForecastFind}
</div>
```

What I'm, after is to let this pass in a variable so I can access any index that I want through the function. **(data.hourly[0] , me getting the first item)**

What I've tried is this: It's obviously not the right syntax but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is.

```js
const [ForecastFind, setForecastFind] = useState(null)
useEffect(choose => {
  var choose = 0
  fetch(
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=22&lon=151&exclude=current,minutely,daily&APPID=TOKEN',
  )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setForecastFind(data.hourly[choose].dt))
}, [])
```

Trying to use the const with a variable:

```js
<div className="DescriptionsSplitter" style={{ marginTop: '-20vh' }}>
  {ForecastFind(1)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**useEffect doesn't pass any params in the callback function**. what you can do is store the entire data in the ForecastFind state and call a function to access what you need

```
const [ForecastFind, setForecastFind] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
      var choose = 0;
      fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=22&lon=151&exclude=current,minutely,daily&APPID=TOKEN')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => setForecastFind(data.hourly));

  }, []);

const getForecast = (choose) => {
    return ((ForecastFind || {})[choose] || {}).dt || null;
}
...

 <div className="DescriptionsSplitter" style={{marginTop:'-20vh'}}>
      {getForecast(1)}
 </div>
```

Comment: @Quentin Updated the post to handle that. However it can be better handled if anything that depends on ForecastFind is not rendered until the data is fetched which is what I assumed the OP would already be doing based on his post

Comment: This works, but for some reason {getForecast(0)} gets the 3rd item instead of the 1st. everythings shifted 2 forward in index.

Comment: By any chance, are you mutating the forecast array somewhere

Comment: I'm not anywhere, the above code that i posted worked when fetching the 0th index item. Super weird

Comment: It might make sense to log ForecastFind array and see if its logging the correct data

Comment: Yep, ill mark yours as the correct answer. Something on my ends gone wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

ForecastFind is not a function so you cannot pass in parameters.
I would suggest to store the whole data.hourly array in ForecastFind like this `setForecastFind(((data.hourly)))`.
Then you can access it like this -

```
<div className="DescriptionsSplitter" style={{marginTop:'-20vh'}}>
   {ForecastFind[1].dt}
</div>
```